# Getting Error: "170375", _id when saving the document mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**Getting Error: "170375", _id when saving the document mongodb?**
how to fix this issue & I don't now what is the exact reason

```
sub.paymentObj.status = 'pending';
sub.paymentObj.paymentState = result.state;
sub.paymentObj.paymentId = result.id;
sub.save().then((savedSub) =>{ 
if (!savedSub) return reject({ message:'Fail update subscription' });
  return resolve({ url: savedSub.paymentObj.paymentUrl });
}).catch((err) => {
  return reject({ message: err.message })
});
```

**Response with error**

```
Error: "170375", _id
at model.checkError (/Users/...../node_modules/plugins/mongoose_errorhandler.js:8:18)
at next (/Users/...../node_modules/kareem/index.js:149:14)
at Kareem.execPost (/Users/...../node_modules/kareem/index.js:197:3)
at /Users/...../node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:227:35
at /Users/...../node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:201:11
at handleCallback (/Users/...../node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:120:56)
at /Users/...../node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1059:42
at /Users/...../node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:469:18
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Comment: Must be some error in the structure of sub object.......try comparing the model structure and the sub object structure you are trying to save

Comment: Please provide more detail like your Model and and  final data to store in DB